# Entity FrameWork CodeFirst- Table name

Tags: entity-framework, datatable, ef-code-first, table-rename

Hi i am building database, with couple tables (products, orders, costumers) and i am interested if it is possible to do such a trick, **generate table every-day based on orders table with name of current day**, because orders table will have about 1000 or more rows every-day and it will hurt application speed.

Comment: 1000 rows a day should not hurt application speed, from my own experience with tables that have millions of rows if they are indexed properly speed should not be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 rows is nothing. What database are you using? Most modern databases can handle millions of rows with no issue, as long as you put some effort into proper indexing of the table.

From your comment, I'm assuming you don't know about database table indexing.

> A database index is a data structure that improves the speed of data
>   retrieval operations on a database table at the cost of slower writes
>   and increased storage space. Indices can be created using one or more
>   columns of a database table, providing the basis for both rapid random
>   lookups and efficient access of ordered records.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

You need to add indexes to your database tables to ensure they can be searched optimally.

What you are suggesting is a bad idea IMO, and it's going to make working with the application a pain. Instead, if you really fill this table with vast amounts of data you could consider periodically archiving old data, but don't do this until you really need to.

Comment: What u mean by proper indexing ?

Comment: plus i think i will be using SQLCE, so it will be one file. It still wont hurt the speed ?

Comment: No. Even SQLCE will be fine. Trust me, databases were designed for LOTS of data. Don't do it. Read up on db design and index your database, and it should be fine.